# bypass and get access while "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser

I have an issue on a website, but I want to connect to this website while having this error, like bypassing and still get the access. How can I do that ?

Comment: Either they have an unintended loop or some miscreant is trying to hide what they are doing. If I see a small number of redirects, I tend to shut the tab down out of an abundance of caution.

Comment: yes, but I really need what's behind, so I need to access the actually thing behind

Comment: Then use curl to download parts of it, modify, then request more, ensuring redirects are not accepted.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do to access it by a browser ?

Comment: Please take some time out to read up on security. I would not touch such sites with a barge pole using a browser.

Comment: Oh not a security problem, it's one of my old website, I just don't have the FTP access anymore

Comment: If it worked before, then you have no idea whether it has been compromised. If you are that desperate, then contact the host and ask for an archive of it.

Comment: he didn't have webarchive, I will try to contact my old host. it stop worked at my last update and never take time to modify it. Thanks for your help !